# Download 3000+ Images Using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, url, download

I have a list of around 3000 image URLs, where I need to download them to my desktop.

I'm a web dev, so naturally wrote a little asp.net c# download method to do this but the obvious problem happened and the page timed out before I got hardly any of them.

Was wondering if anyone else knew of a good, quick and robust way of me looping through all the image URL's and downloading them to a folder?  Open to any suggestions, WinForms, batch file although I'm a novice at both.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)? It can download a list of URL specified in a file.

```
wget -i c:\list-of-urls.txt
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I've used this before but for getting a web page

Comment: This probably won't affect you, but be aware that older versions of wget get squiffy when download size exceeds 2 (or perhaps 4) gigabytes. The linked to version will almost certainly suffer this issue. http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/ is more up to date.

Comment: @spender: Updated link directly to the GnuWin32 project: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: I used wget64 for Windows. Worked great.

Answer (score 11):

Write a C# command-line application (or Winforms, if that's your inclination), and use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class to retrieve the files.

Here are some tutorials:

[C# WebClient Tutorial](http://dotnetperls.com/webclient)

[Using WebClient to Download a File](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial66_Using-WebClient-to-download-a-file.html)

or, [just Google C# WebClient](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+webclient).

You'll either need to provide a list of files to download and loop through the list, issuing a request for each file and saving the result, or issue a request for the index page, parse it using something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to find all of the image tags, and then issue a request for each image, saving the result somewhere on your local drive.

**Edit**

If you just want to do this once (as in, not as part of an application), [mbeckish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442674/download-3000-images-using-c#answer-4442719) makes the most sense.

Comment: Definitely the easiest. If you can, use `Parallel.ForEach()` to speed up your download.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` Sweet - I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: I've never heard of that either, I'm going to go and have a look at it for my own future reference :)  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You might want to use an existing download manager like Orbit, rather than writing your own program for the purpose. (blasphemy, I know)

I've been pretty happy with Orbit. It lets you import a list of downloads from a text file. It'll manage the connections, downloading portions of each file in parallel with multiple connections, to increase the speed of each download. It'll take care of retrying if connections time out, etc. It seems like you'd have to go to a lot of effort to build these kind of features from scratch.

Comment: But where's the fun in that? +1

Comment: I know, I'm such a killjoy. :-)

Comment: Just be sure to uncheck all the adware options in the installer.

Answer (score 6):

If this is just a one-time job, then one easy solution would be to write a HTML page with img tags pointing to the URLs.

Then browse it with FireFox and use an extension to save all of the images to a folder.

Comment: Good idea thanks :)  I'll try the wget idea and use this as a backup

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumption that this is a one off run once project and as you are a novice with other technologies I would suggest the following:

Rather than try and download all 3000 images in one web request do one image per request.  When the image download is complete redirect to the same page passing the URL of the next image to get as a query string parameter.  Download that one and then repeat until all images are downloaded.

Not what I would call a "production" solution, but if my assumption is correct it is a solution that will have you up an running in no time.

Another fairly simple solution would be to create a simple C# console application that uses WebClient to download each of the images.  The following psuedo code should give you enough to get going:

```
List<string> imageUrls = new List<string>();
imageUrls.Add(..... your urls from wherever .....)

foreach(string imageUrl in imagesUrls)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] raw = client.DownloadData(imageUrl);

        .. write raw .. to file
    }
}
```

Comment: you would most likely look into using Parallel.ForEach() for looping over those imagesUrls

Answer (score 0):

I've written a similar app in WinForms that loops through URLs in an Excel spreadsheet and downloads the image files.  I think they problem you're having with implementing this as a web application is that server will only allow the process to run for a short amount of time before the request from your browser times out.  You could either increase this time in the web.config file (change the executionTimeout attribute of the httpRuntime element), or implement this functionality as a WinForms application where the long execution time won't be a problem.  If this is more than a throw-away application and you decide to go the WinForms route, you may want to add a progress bar to ind